# Get absolut path to tmux.conf in tmux configuration file

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm desperately trying to extract the absolute path of the tmux.conf file (which is a symbolic link) within the file itself. Usually one can achieve this easily in bash with:

`file_dir=$(dirname $(realpath -f $0))`

But I'm not sure how to achieve this in tmux.conf.

Some background:
I have a repo which holds my config of tmux I use on several machines. All I want to do is clone the repo set the symbolic link and the tmux.conf figures out where the repo and all the necessary files are located. But therefore I need to have knowledge about the absolute path of the symbolic link. I don't want to add anything to bashrc or create a other script which triggers the tmux.conf.

Anyone suggestions how to achieve this?

As @Nicholas Marriott pointed out this works like charm! Thanks.

```
run -b 'tmux set-env -g TMUX_PLUGIN_MANAGER_PATH "$(dirname $(realpath -f $HOME/.tmux.conf))/plugins/"'
ran -b '$(dirname $(realpath -f $HOME/.tmux.conf)/plugins/tpm/tpm)'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the path of the config file like `$0` but if you know its location and just want to know where it points you can do, for example:

```
run 'tmux set -g @conf_dir "$(dirname $(realpath -f ~/.tmux.conf))"'
```

Then use `#{@conf_dir}`.

But note that `source-file` does not expand formats, so you can't just do `source-file "#{@conf_dir}/*.conf"` - you will have to use `run-shell` which does, for example:

```
run 'tmux source "#{@conf_dir}/*.conf"'
```

Also because you are setting a user option it will not be available until the command is run, so not at parse time.

Answer (score 0):

```
tmux display-message -p "#{config_files}"
/pathto/config/tmux/config
```

see `man tmux` > `FORMATS`:

```
config_files                    List of configuration files loaded
```